# updating html text on click

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I would appreciate some guidance on which direction to take regarding a front-end design.

Context:

I am trying to create a page where I have 10 buttons on a top panel. Underneath this top panel will be a main panel containing N boxes of text.

Depending on what button in the top panel is clicked or active (default-button1), I want the boxes in the main panel to display the relevant boxes of text.

Example:

A restaurant menu where you have categories such as Food, Drinks, Desserts at the top. And a section which updates and shows the various options dependent on which category has been selected.

A minimal example:

3 buttons or links as Category1, Category2, Category3

Category1 should have 5 paragraphs.
Category2 should have 3 paragaraphs.
Category3 should have 8 paragraphs.

I am looking for an efficient way to implement this. Any pointers?

I understand the DOM allows one to dynamically render HTML using the call below, but I am confused as to how to 'grow' elements with this static approach. I am determined to learn more JavaScript.

```
document.getElementsByClassName(“”).innerHTML = "New text"
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
   <style>
   </style>
 </head>  
 <body>
   <div class = "main_content">
    <nav>
      <ul id = "categories">
        <li>Cat 1</a></li>
        <li>Cat 2</li>
        <li>Cat 3</li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

    <article class = "items_list">
      <section class ="items">
          <!--# of <p> elements and inner HTML text for each element depends on which <li> element is currently active -->
        <p>Item A</p>
      </section>
      <section class = "items">
        <p>Item B</p>
      </section>
      <section class = "items">
        <p>Item C</p>
      </section>
    </article>
  </div>
 
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: So, you'll need to set up "event handlers" for your buttons that trigger on the `click` event. These handlers associate a "callback" function with an event so that when the event occurs, the function is called. This is done with the [`.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) Global method. But, Stack Overflow really isn't the place to learn JavaScript. You should look at: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For every Category/Button you need to add **Event Handler** which will trigger a function on the event of **onClick**.
Then according to your requirements, you can add and remove classes on paragraphs which will let you show and hide them.

Those classes can simply have **display:none** or **display:block** on it.